# Storing Multiple Images In A Variable With Action Script 3 In Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have a flash assignment that I need help getting started, any advice would be greatly appreciated. The assignment is to create an application for playing a card game, I have to create an MXML component that has two variables, one variable stores the image of the back of a playing card, the other variable has t store all 52 options of a front facing card (the second variable will store over 50 images).

I've written the variable for the back of the card image like this:

```
public var backOfCard:Image = new Image();
backofCard.source = 'asset/backImage';
```

However I get an undefined variable error (1120: Access of undefined propery variable img1), I feel like there's something small that I'm missing here, but I was wondering if anyone could spot it.

I'd also like to know if I should use the same method for each jpg image for the front of the cards, it seems like it would be a lot of repetitive code aside from the change in filename for the front of the card images.

Here's a snippet of the homework assignment, again I just need help getting this part correct, I really appreciate any help with this.

> Your job is to supply the custom component named Card. Create the
>   component by using File → New → MXML Component. In the popup dialog
>   box
>
> leave the Package blank
>
> Name the component Card
>
> Base Card on spark.components.Image
>
> What goes into the Card component?
>
> For each card, we'll want to be able to show the front face of the
>   card, or its back face. That means each card should have a place to
>   store information about what file to show as its front face, and what
>   file to show as its back face.
>
> To do this, create two variables in the Card component to store the
>   file names. You might call these variables backImage and frontImage.

Comment: It seems to me you're leaving some things out. For instance, if you were populating a public variable right in line with where it is declared, you'd get a compile error.  But also, it seems there should be an img1 variable somewhere in your project related to the error. You need to show the code that contains it, as well as giving the relationship between it and the code above.

Comment: PS MPO is that the back of the card should be set through CSS, and should not be part of the data for a card, since it is the same for all cards.

Comment: Thanks Amy, I'm new to this stuff, and didn't realize that I was missing something until you pointed it out. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your access modifier is what's bothering me.

If you're creating these definitions in your class file, then the first statement works:

```
public var backOfCard:Image = new Image();
```

But if you're in one of the methods, usually the constructor (sometimes called the ctor), or any other method of the application, you could use the 2nd statement:

```
backofCard.source = 'asset/backImage';
```

But the combination of both is what I think is confusing. Because the "access modifier" [(i.e. public, private, internal, protected)](http://blog.oinam.com/2005/access-modifiers-in-actionscript-30/) is what you use to define variables and methods within a class. And since you're putting both side-by-side (a definition and an assignment statement), I think you're mixing when to declare them.